# Really weird performance issues Minecraft Java Edition

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos, performance

First off, I am using a really old macbook pro from 2012 with a core i5 2nd generation which is really old, but I got some pleasant results. (This isn't my main PC; it's just an old laptop.) What I noticed is that when I went to activity monitor (aka task manager on windows), Minecraft isn't using the entire cpu. For some reason it's using less than 30% which is really weird, and that's why I sometimes get lag spikes. Is there a reason for this? If there is, how do I fix it? I want it to use as much as it needs. Even after maxing out the render distance, it still isn't using much at all.

Will something like sodium work?

Comment: "*Minecraft isn't using the entire cpu. For some reason it's using less than 30% which is really weird*" ... What's being weird here? My CPU (Core i7 12700KF) does not use that much of usage. Minecraft only eats 10% or below. Never had any issue. I think it's just your PC is just weak. Judging that yours are only having i5, I suspect that it doesn't have GPU (even though it's MBP). That could be the culprit, if I may say.

Comment: well you are sort of right. it has an integrated gpu with 512mb. So is that why? although i usually play Minecraft java on another laptop that has 128mb but a core i3 10th gen with basically no lag at all (and it uses 100% cpu).

Comment: I apologize my wording. Your 2nd gen i5's iGPU(integrated GPU) means almost nothing in terms of GPU; it just functions to provide images to your display/monitor. That's why I said it doesn't have GPU(more specifically, discrete GPU). 10th gen i3's iGPU (UHD 630 if I recall correctly) can actually handle some 3D games such as Skyrim (of course without mods). That's why it's working flawlessly for you. I have no idea why yours are having 100% cpu usage, though.

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense. Tbh that MacBook feels really slow. Especially with just using Chrome. So basically the i5 is worse?

Comment: Not that i5 in genral is worse, your gen2 i5 is worse.

Comment: Thats sad. But like how far of is it? I even asked chatgpt to compare it but i dont trust it lol. it said 50% difference.

Comment: you didn't specify which model of it but assuming that it's the best at that time then: [53.7% difference](https://www.cpubenchmark.net/compare/812vs3560/Intel-i5-2540M-vs-Intel-i3-1005G1).

Comment: Wow. Well thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

The lagspikes are not caused due to your processor. If minecraft needed the entire CPU, it will use. The main problem might be with the amount of RAM that you have allocated to the launcher, or has been set by default. Firstly, it depends on what launcher you are using. Based on your launcher, you can browse through the settings and you will find an option for increasing RAM Allocation. Also try updating Java Runtime Environment.

If you are still facing lag issues, try reducing Render distance and *Simulation distance (*if you are playing MC 1.18 or above).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmm but i gave it 12gb of ram.

Comment: Then, either your Java Runtime version is older or the launcher is not using the processor. Try updating Java Runtime Environment, or backup the versions folder and the worlds folder then reinstall the launcher. This should fix the problem. Also, you can try lowering the Minecraft Video settings.

Comment: Yeah i tried all of those things. And my chunks is only 7 with sodium too. Tbh it seems ok anways.

Comment: If it still lags, try removing sodium and use other versions like optifine. Fabric versions sometimes cause some performance issues.